# Integrating 2 push buttons to toggle the LED ON and OFF

Tags: arduino-uno, led, button

Hey guys need your help in verifying out this program about toggling the LED ON and OFF using 2 push buttons.What i actually want is to let my LED stay ON when i press and even leave the push button-1 , and on pressing and leaving the push button-2 i want the led to turn off and no matter how many times i press the push button-1 i want it to turn ON the LED and the push button-2 should only turn off the LED.but with my program i am only able to see the LED to be at HIGH state,It is not shifting to LOW state on clicking push button-2.

This is my sketch :-

```c
    /* LED CONTROLLED WITH 2 PUSH BUTTON PROJECT
       BY ARSH BANSAL 

 CIRCUIT :-
 i) LEDPIN CONNECTED PIN 13.
 ii) PUSHBUTTON1 CONNECTED TO PIN 8.
 iii) PUSHBUTTON2 CONNECTED TO PIN 7.
 iv) BOTH THE PUSH BUTTONS CONNECTED PARALLELY, EACH WITH A 1K PULLUP RESISTOR AND BOTH THE PUSH BUTTONS CONNECTED TO 5V SUPPLY.
   */

 int ledpin = 13;
 int pushbutton1 = 8;
 int pushbutton2 = 7;
 boolean lastbuttonstate1 = LOW;
 boolean lastbuttonstate2 = LOW;

 void setup() 
 { 
   pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(pushbutton1,INPUT);
   pinMode(pushbutton2,INPUT);
 }

 void loop()
 {
   if ( digitalRead(pushbutton1)== HIGH && digitalRead(pushbutton2) == LOW && lastbuttonstate1 == LOW )
    { digitalWrite (ledpin,HIGH) ;}

   else ( digitalRead(pushbutton1) == LOW && digitalRead(pushbutton2)== LOW && lastbuttonstate1 == HIGH)
    ; { digitalWrite (ledpin,HIGH) ; }

    if ( digitalRead(pushbutton1)== LOW && digitalRead(pushbutton2) == HIGH  && lastbuttonstate2 == LOW)
    { digitalWrite (ledpin,LOW) ;}

   else ( digitalRead(pushbutton1) == LOW && digitalRead(pushbutton2)== LOW  && lastbuttonstate2 == HIGH)
    ; { digitalWrite (ledpin,LOW) ; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off, in this case, remembering the state of the LED not the state of the buttons:

- If the LED is OFF and BUTTON1 is PRESSED then turn the LED on.
- If the LED is ON and BUTTON2 is PRESSED then turn the LED off.

For example:

```
void loop() {
    static bool ledState = false; // LED is off by default
    if ((digitalRead(pushbutton1) == LOW) && !ledState) { // 1 pressed & led is off
        digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
        ledState = true;
    }
    if ((digitalRead(pushbutton2) == LOW) && ledState) { // 2 pressed & led is on
        digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);
        ledState = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just understood my mistake i should have used if statement after else to check the respective conditions well thanks for your efforts.